# Gravity Forms + jQuery + PHP + ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, gravityforms

Well. This is complicated, so I'll explain it the best I can.

**What Works:** If you visit https://goatthroat.com, you will see a Gravity Forms form on the homepage with the heading "Find the Right Pump." Here is how this form works:

1. 1. I have uploaded a CSV that is a table of ALL of these chemicals and their pump compatibility (see https://www.goatthroat.com/support/complete-chemical-liquid-compatibility-guide/ -- which is a table also generated by this CSV)
2. The dropdown menu on this FIND THE RIGHT PUMP form is automatically populated from that CSV
3. The user enters the info as prompted, and it generates a query string to return the appropriate results (i.e. https://www.goatthroat.com/pump-recommendation/?chem=3M+Adhesion+Promoter+4298UV)

**Goal:** On another form on another page (https://goatthroat.com/quote-request), there is ANOTHER dropdown with the same list of chemicals.

I would like to be able to incorporate their search results IN THE FORM. In other words (and I know this may seem unclear): fetch, using ajax I assume, the results of this form search LIVE and include them in the form submission.

This is a bit more technical than I usually get, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you can also save into session or cookies the previous search results and fetch them back, when on the other page....

Comment: Interesting thought. I'm actually already doing it when they've executed that search, but I can't require them to do the search before filling out this quote request.

Comment: You dont need them to do the search before hand. Just if they did it, u use the data..

Comment: That's beforehand. They didn't NECESSARILY just do it. Maybe they did, but they can go directly to the quote request without ever doing the search.

Comment: That’s what I’m saying.... in such case just test if session or cookie is empty and move on for quote...